# could-not-apply-the-stored-configuration-for-monitors

Tags: display-resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 VM box and getting the error message while logging in says

```
could-not-apply-the-stored-configuration-for-monitors 
CRTC 381: trying mode 640x480 with output at 1024x768 (pass 0)
CRTC 381: trying mode 640x480 with output at 1024x768 (pass 1)
```

Could anyone help me to sort out this issue? I am unable change the monitor resolution from "640x480" that is too small and I couldn't be able to work in the VM box normally. Monitor resolution plays a weird role here.